# html css tabs handle clips and sizes of tabs

Tags: html, css

I want to use tabs that I made with HTML and CSS only I don't use javascript at all, but I have some issues that I can not fix .. so I need your help.
so I got two questions I hope that I will be clear and you understand my problems :

1. how can I fix the problem of tabs clip when I resize the screen(or use phone)
   [image: example]
2. can I sperate the tabs on the ALL contact block without care of tabs numbers?
   [image: example]

here the code
    http://jsfiddle.net/waL0d6gu/

```css
.tabss {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px;
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;

  
}
.tabb {
  float: left;
  margin-right:3px;




}
.tabb label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 7px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;



}
.tabb [type=radio] {
  display: none;  
 
}
.contentt {

  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: #11426f;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  display:none;
  min-width:700px;
  color:white;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: #11426f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #11426f;
  color:white;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 75px;

}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .contentt {
  display:block;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  width:95%

}
```

```html
<div class="tabss">
<div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked="checked" /> <label for="tab-1"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i><span>&nbsp;</span>aaaaa</label>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="contentt">[[aaaaa]]</div>
</div>
<div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-2"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> bbbbb</label>
<div class="contentt">[[bbbb]]</div>
</div>
<div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-3"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><span>&nbsp;</span>dddddd</label>
<div class="contentt">[[dddddd]]</div>
<div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-4"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i> cccccc</label>
<div class="contentt">[[cccccc]]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the third tabb has inside another tabb, i think is not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using float left - right, I used display flex and added media query for responsive. I just added it for mobile view. You can add whatever you want to the other views yourself. I wrote down my additions and changes in the comment lines. Good Luck!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* added */
}

.tabss {
  width: 100%;
  /* added */
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  display: flex;
  /* added */
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* added */
}

.tabb label {
  display: flex;
  /* added */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* added */
  align-items: center;
  /* added */
  background: #eee;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  /* changed */
  padding-right: 40px;
  /* changed */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabb [type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.contentt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  background: #11426f;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

[type="radio"]:checked~label {
  background: #11426f;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #11426f;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 75px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked~label~.contentt {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* added all , you can configure what you want*/

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .tabb label {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  [type="radio"]:checked~label {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dc0c634418.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="tabss">
    <div class="tabb">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked="checked" />
      <label for="tab-1">
        <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i class> </i>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>aaaaa
      </label>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="contentt">[[aaaaa]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-2"><i
          class="fa fa-truck"></i> bbbbb</label>
      <div class="contentt">[[bbbb]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-3"><i
          class="fa fa-info-circle"></i><span>&nbsp;</span>dddddd</label>
      <div class="contentt">[[dddddd]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabb"><input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-1" /> <label for="tab-4"><i
          class="fas fa-undo"></i> cccccc</label>
      <div class="contentt">[[cccccc]]</div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its ımpossible. what do you mean I didn't work either ? are you using something you're not telling us? like bootstrap, for example ?

Comment: sorry find my mistake,  thanks a lot for yours helping

Answer (score 0):

What CanUver said is correct, css media queries can be set to whichever device display you want, for example this certain view would work on devices with a 1920x1080 display *ONLY*. Or else you could use the bootstrap framework, however im not sure if they cater for resizing of anything unrelated to what they provide.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Put these in your `<head>` element, and make sure to put the bootstrap link before any other link in the `<head>` element as stated by the bootstrap site itself. Should work I think :)

Comment: hi thanks for your response ' it doesn't work for me :(